# How can I output the name of the month?

Tags: mysql

How can I output the name of the month? Given this sql statement. Could some help me please..

```
 select MONTHNAME(MONTH(date_loan_granted), '%m') from loan_assignment;
```

Comment: @soyan: Thanks to MaveRick: `select MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(date_loan_granted), '%m')) from loan_assignment;`. Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but it's still have syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try out this:**
     select MONTHNAME(date_loan_granted) from loan_assignment;